# how do add photos to my html from my docs

Tags: javascript, html

I can't find any method that allows me to cycle through the photos unless I have one the code I have right now is below. I couldn't find the error in my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <img id="light">

        <script>
            var list= ['':]; //this is where i would have the web address but its not efficent as it soetimes dosent load
            var i = 0;
            function lightsCycle() {

                i = (i < list.length - 1) ? ++i : 0;

                document.getElementById("light2").src = list[i];
            }

        </script>

        <button type="button" onclick="lightsCycle()">Next Light</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

ok so a few days later i have now updated my code i have this i have put all the images in a folder called assests and they are all the correct names yet nothing works i just get taken to the 201% page

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>   
  <p>This is  my Traffic Light script</p> 
  <img id="light" src="./assets/red.jpg">
  <button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>  
  <script> 
    var list = ["./assets/red.jpg","./assets/redamber.jpg", "./assets/green.jpg","./assets/amber.jpg" ];
    var index = 0;
    function changeLights() {
      index = index + 1;      
      if (index == list.length) 
        index = 0;      
      var image = document.getElementById('light');     
      image.src = list[index]; 
    } 
  </script>  
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you had a basic problem, ure pointing to ID `light2` and ur img tag only says `light` hehe

ive tried and everyworks fine, also i added a base image to load first, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/dou30sqp/

Comment: ok so i tried to do what you have given me but i get an error 201% any idea what that means ?

Comment: 201 is used for may reasons. there should be error message to it. 201 is status code.

Comment: hmm weird, anyways i uploaded the code in another editor (remember to press RUN button to test): https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD7QHIFYVBYO